# mongoose not connected to mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Mongoose is not connected to MongoDB server

Made sure password and username is correct

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const uri ="mongodb+srv://halbr:password@cluster0-t2noa.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(uri).then(
    () => {
        console.log('Connect to Mongo');
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Error connecting to Mongo:")
        console.log(err);
    }

);

module.exports = mongoose.connection
```

Comment: How are you accessing this script ? any error, how are you saying not connected, is that Connect to Mongo not getting printed ?

Comment: Yes it is not getting printed

Comment: it looks good, but can you check on using below code.

Comment: I pasted this code to another project,which already was connecting with MongoDB previously. And it works on that project. Do I need to install any other modules, dependency for this to work in my current project?

Comment: going back to my original question, how are you accessing it ? Can you put a log before connect and check if this file is being accessed properly or not..

Comment: @srinivasy Added this to server.js(main file for node.js) 
         const dbConnection = require('./database') (folder containing the above code and schemas)  and it is working now
I donot know why it is working though. dbConnection isn't used anywhere

Comment: anyhow if it's working cool !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this sample :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

async function myDbConnection() {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://halbr:password@cluster0-t2noa.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    try {
        let connectionPromise = await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        if (mongoose.connection) {
            console.log('Connected Successfully')
            global.connectionPromise = connectionPromise;
        } else { global.connectionPromise = null; 
                 console.log('not connected to DB') }
        return connectionPromise;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error connecting to DB ::', error);
    }
}

module.exports = myDbConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks @srinivasy. But it still isn't working. Server console doesnot show any error message

Comment: @duncan : yes as I said, your code also looks good but not sure why - just made couple of changes, did you try connecting your cluster with any client like mongo compass/robo3T or if not sometimes clusters need role to be created explicitly try that?

Comment: @duncan : what is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: MongoDB Version 4.0.12

Comment: @duncan : Can you name a database in the cluster ?

Comment: Yes I can name a database in cluster

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify that you added your public IP in IP Whitelist, for testing you can add wildcard. `0.0.0.0/0` , if it's okay you can try to connect to db through command line of it's not working I recommend to add new user with root role and check connection again.

```
use admin
 db.createUser(
 {
   user: "admin",
   pwd: "password",
   roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
 }
);
exit;
```

Comment: Added a wild card 0.0.0.0/0 and added new user, but still not working

Comment: So, please try [this solution](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6106#issuecomment-364058024)  `mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    // Hack the database back to the right one, because when using mongodb+srv as protocol.
    if (mongoose.connection.client.s.url.startsWith('mongodb+srv')) {
        mongoose.connection.db = mongoose.connection.client.db('yourDatabase');
    }
    console.log('Connection to Mongo established.')
});
mongoose.connect(...);`

Comment: Did it works when you tried to contact through terminal ?